# Commenting on Checklist Items

Tags: trello

Can one add a comment to a checklist item and keep it a checklist item?  Would prefer not to convert to card if possible.

Answer (score 2):

No, for now comments are for the card.  Maybe mark the checklist item with an asterisk and then include a comment on the card that starts with an asterisk to correlate the two.  Sort of like a footnote in a book.